# Program in wxPython and VPython

Tags: python, wxpython, vpython

I wrote program in wxPython and VPython, but I have huge problem: Module VPython not always run. If I run program in Interpreter, program run more often , than after compilation. Code never returns any errors. I try on the other computers, program is the same.

Win7
Python 2.7.5 32bit
wxPython 2.9.4
VPython 6.0.5

```
import visual as v
import wx

class Maintest(v.window):
    def InitUI(self):
        fileMenu = wx.Menu()


        self.menubar.Append(fileMenu, '&Plik')
        self.menubar.Remove(0)

    def asd(self, scene):
        v.box()


def main():
    w = Maintest(menus=True, title="program", x=100, y=100, width=1024, height=600)
    w.InitUI()
    scene = v.display(window=w, x=0, y=0, width=600, height=600,  up=(0,0,1), background=(1,1,1), foreground = (0,1,0), forward=(-1,-1,-1))
    w.asd(scene)
    while True:
        v.rate(60)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

All is OK: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/199/tpp.png/
Not OK: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/689/akun.png/

It is only the part of main program, but problem  is the same.
What is wrong? What I should to do?
I will be gratefull for answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Win7 Python 2.7.5 64bit wxPython 2.9.4 VPython 6.0.5 I cannot get the program to fail. The fact that the problem is not entirely reproducible (and is entirely nonreproducible by me) suggests the possibility that the graphics driver needs to be updated. VPython uses the OpenGL 3D graphics library, which is sensitive to driver issues.

Answer (score 0):

Only a guess but you may have let something out:

```
import wx

app = wx.App(redirect=True)
top = wx.Frame(None, title="Hello World", size=(300,200))
top.Show() # you need this
app.MainLoop() # you need this
```

Comment: I change "main" and exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, or at least one with similar symptoms, and found that it was dependant on the position of the mouse at launch time (see full description [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21639508/vpython-display-module-not-showing-properly-when-embedded-in-a-window)).

The solution was to call Hide and Show in succession after the display was created.

These calls need to be made to the panel fed to the display object.

win.panel.Hide()
   win.panel.Show()